# Joining two table with OR clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem with my query results. I have 2 tables that I want to join with specific join to get all the informations about it and a or condition that doesnt include second table. There is my tables :

```
main_orders:

id | destination
----------
1  |  London
2  |  Germany
2  |  Netherland
3  |  Polska
4  |  JP

includes:

id | rel_id
----------
1  |  2
1  |  3
```

here id number 1 is the main order and it also covers the rest of the orders show as in the second table with rel_id

i want to select the order details of id 1 from main_orders and also the orders that relate to this id

my query is,

```
SELECT a.id FROM main_orders a, includes b
where (a.id = 1) OR (b.id = 1 and a.id = b.rel_id)
```

it works only when there is any relative orders in the second table, please help the result should be as follows

```
RESULTANT ROWS:

id | destination
----------
1  |  London
2  |  Germany
2  |  Netherland
3  |  Polska
```

Thanks

Comment: By using `SELECT a.id FROM main_orders a, includes b` you create a cross join, which is the cartesian product of your tables. You should rather use an inner join and a where clause

Comment: Did you *really* mean for `main_orders.id` to be non-unique?  What's the PK in that table?

Comment: PK is another column named serial and it is auto increment

Answer (score 3):

you could use an exists clause:

```
SELECT a.id, a.destination FROM 
main_orders a
where a.id = 1 
or exists (select null 
                          from includes b 
                          where  b.rel_id = a.id
                          and b.id =1);
```

see [sqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc890/11)

Comment: a problem with this it also fetching the id's that doesn't relate

Comment: SELECT a.id, a.destination FROM 
main_orders a
where a.id = 1 
or exists (select null 
                          from includes b 
                          where  b.id = 1 and b.rel_id = a.id);

Comment: @RowanSan oh, I put that first, and thought that wasn't needed (was not with your sample datas)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

SELECT a.id FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.id=b.id GROUP BY a.id;

(obviously use your table names)

Comment: Tried, that query not working, it gives duplicates of 1 same as my query

Comment: You need a group by then.  Edited to add the grouping

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT      main_orders.id, main_orders.destination
FROM        main_orders
  LEFT JOIN includes ON includes.rel_id = main_orders.id
WHERE       main_orders.id = 1 OR includes.id = 1
```

See it on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cf90e/1/0).

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
SELECT a.id FROM main_orders a, includes b
where (b.id=1 and (a.id=b.rel_id or a.id=1 ))
```